# How to drag and drop entire rows between different tables in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, drag-and-drop

I am new to JavaFx and GUI in general, so please take it easy on me.

I am developing some sort of an MP3 Player application and I am currently at the GUI part. I basically have a table view in the middle of my application, which is basically my library, where you could import from a folder. I created a new Table to the left of that, which is basically the playlist, and I am trying to implement the functionality, that the users can drag and drop multiple rows from the library, into the playlist.

Here is a picture of how it looks so far to help you visualize it:
[Application GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GYRU.png)

I've searched on here and on google and all of the examples I could find where about copying specific cells in the same table and so forth, but in my case I am trying to copy an entire object (row) from the library to the playlist.

I'd be grateful if somebody can help me out with this.

Here are some relevant parts of the code:

Some parts of the initialize method in my controller class.

```
 public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // Initialize Library Table
    imageColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, Image>("picture"));
    nameColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("songTitle"));
    artistColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("artist"));
    albumColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("album"));
    trackNumColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("trackNumber"));
    genreColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("genre"));
    dateColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("date"));
    copyrightColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("copyrightInformation"));
    webpageColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("publisherWebpage"));
    ratingColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, String>("rating"));
    playCounterColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Table, Integer>("playCounter"));

    ratingData.add("");
    ratingData.add("*");
    ratingData.add("**");
    ratingData.add("***");
    ratingData.add("****");
    ratingData.add("*****");

    ratingColumnID.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter(), ratingData));
    ratingColumnID.setEditable(true);
    ratingColumnID.setOnEditCommit(e -> handleRating());

    library = new SongLibrary();

    // library table
    tableID.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    tableID.setRowFactory(e -> {
        TableRow<Table> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnMouseClicked(ev -> {
            if (ev.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && ev.getClickCount() == 2)
                handleMouseClick();
        });
        row.setOnDragDetected(ev1 -> dragAndDropIntoPlaylist());
        return row;
    });


    // Initialize Playlist Table
    playlistSongTitle.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PlaylistTable, String>("songTitle"));
    playlistArtist.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PlaylistTable, String>("artist"));
    playlistAlbum.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PlaylistTable, String>("album"));
    playlistTracknr.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PlaylistTable, String>("trackNumber"));

    playlistTable.setRowFactory(e -> {
        TableRow<PlaylistTable> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.setOnDragDropped(ev -> dragAndDropIntoPlaylist());
        return row;
    });
 }
```

The library table constructor:

```
    public Table(Song song) {
    this.song = song;
    this.metadata = song.getMetadata();

    // handle picture
    if (metadata.getPicture().isPresent()) {
        Image img = convertToJavaFXImage(metadata.getPicture().get().getData(), 50, 50);
        ImageView image = new ImageView(img);
        image.setFitHeight(30);
        image.setFitWidth(30);
        image.prefHeight(30);
        image.prefWidth(30);
        image.maxHeight(30);
        image.maxWidth(30);
        this.picture = new SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView>(image);
    } else {
        this.picture = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    }
    this.songTitle = new SimpleStringProperty(metadata.getSongTitle().orElse(""));
    this.artist = new SimpleStringProperty(metadata.getArtist().orElse(""));
    this.album = new SimpleStringProperty(metadata.getAlbumTitle().orElse(""));
    this.trackNumber = metadata.getTrackNumber().isPresent() ?
            new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(metadata.getTrackNumber().get())) : new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.genre = metadata.getGenre().isPresent() ?
            new SimpleStringProperty(metadata.getGenre().get().getName()) : new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.date = metadata.getDate().isPresent() ?
            new SimpleStringProperty(metadata.getDate().get().toString().substring(0, 4)) : new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.copyrightInformation = metadata.getCopyrightInformation().isPresent() ?
            new SimpleStringProperty(metadata.getCopyrightInformation().get().toString()) : new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.publisherWebpage = metadata.getPublisherWebpage().isPresent() ?
            new SimpleStringProperty(metadata.getPublisherWebpage().get().toString()) : new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.rating = metadata.getRating().isPresent() ?
            new SimpleStringProperty(String.valueOf(metadata.getRating().get())) : new SimpleStringProperty();
    this.playCounter = metadata.getPlayCounter().isPresent() ?
            new SimpleIntegerProperty(metadata.getPlayCounter().get()) : new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

}
```

The Playlist table constructor:

```
public PlaylistTable(Table row){
    this.song = row.getSong();
    this.songTitle = new SimpleStringProperty(row.getSongTitle());
    this.artist = new SimpleStringProperty(row.getArtist());
    this.album = new SimpleStringProperty(row.getAlbum());
    this.trackNumber = new SimpleStringProperty(row.getTrackNumber());
}
```

My idea is that I could choose a bunch of rows from library and drag and drop them into the playlist, basically transferring the rows from type "Table" which would then be passed to the constructor of Playlist Table and then added to that table's observable list, but I am not really sure how to implement that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603224/sort-tableview-with-drag-and-drop-rows)? It has drag and drop within the same table, but the idea is pretty much the same; you would have row factories on both tables and register the `onDragDetected` handler on the first table (library) and the `onDragOver` and `onDragDropped` handlers on the second table (play list).

Comment: @James_D yes I did, the thing I'm not sure how to implement from that solution is this part "content.putString(idx.toString());". How could I add an object to the clipboard? I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: Well, since that's not part of the solution, it's not clear why you would be using it. The version in the solution makes the index the content of the dragboard directly: all it is doing is storing the index of the item that is being dragged, relative to the source table (library in your case) backing list.

Comment: The underlying issue is that you can only put `String`s, `Image`s, and `Serializable` objects into the drag board. It's pretty difficult to make an object you're using in a `TableView` serializable (because JavaFX properties are not serializable), and anyway, you almost certainly don't want to serialize/unserialize the object because you would get a new instance of it; you likely want both tables to be displaying the same instance. So the easiest thing to do is just to transfer the index of the object, and look it back up from the table's backing list.

Comment: @James_D right, that makes sense. I seem to have overcomplicated it in my head. I'll give it a show with the index and it should work. I'm also implementing a right click functionality at the moment, which should also do the same thing. 

Thank you!

Comment: @James_D it worked, thanks again. Just another quick question, in order for the drag and drop to work, there has to be some elements in the Playlist already. It doesn't seem to work when the Playlist is empty. Would you perhaps know what could be causing this?

Comment: If the table is empty, no rows are shown... So you probably want a separate handler on the table itself for drag over and drag dropped that implements "if the table is empty, add the dropped item".

Comment: Ah alright, thanks!