# JavaFx OnDragDropped/OnDragOver TableView with No Contents

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, event-listener

I am busy working on a small project that involves 3 TableViews each having their own drag listener.

I have been working on being able to drag and drop rows from one table to another. It is working the way it is intended with active rows within the model. However, when there are no rows (no content), it does not allow the OnDragOver and OnDragDropp callbacks to be triggered and I do not understand why.

I have spent time looking on StackOverFlow or rethinking my code, but I have come short. Any assistance would be great!

I have declared the drag listeners to span across all 3 tables:

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ...
        addDragListener(tableView1);
        addDragListener(tableView2);
        addDragListener(tableView3);
        ...
    }
```

Here is the drag listener I currently have across all 3 tables:

```
private void addDragListener(TableView<MediaItem> tableView) {
        tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<MediaItem> row = new TableRow<>();

            row.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
                tableSource = tableView;
                //System.out.println("setOnDragDetected");
                if (!row.isEmpty()) {
                    Integer index = row.getIndex();
                    Dragboard db = row.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                    db.setDragView(row.snapshot(null, null));
                    ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
                    cc.put(SERIALIZED_MIME_TYPE, index);
                    db.setContent(cc);
                    event.consume();
                }
            });

            row.setOnDragOver(event -> {
                //System.out.println("setOnDragOver");
                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();

                if (db.hasContent(SERIALIZED_MIME_TYPE)) {
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
                    event.consume();
                }
            });

            row.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
                //System.out.println("setOnDragDropped");
                Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                if (db.hasContent(SERIALIZED_MIME_TYPE)) {

                    int draggedIndex = (Integer) db.getContent(SERIALIZED_MIME_TYPE);
                    MediaItem draggedMediaItem = tableSource.getItems().remove(draggedIndex);

                    int dropIndex = 0;

                    if (!tableSource.equals(tableView)) {

                        if (row.isEmpty()) {
                            dropIndex = tableView.getItems().size();
                        } else {
                            dropIndex = row.getIndex();
                        }
                    } 

                    tableView.getItems().add(dropIndex, draggedMediaItem);
                    event.setDropCompleted(true);                    
                    tableSource.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                    tableView.getSelectionModel().select(dropIndex);
                    event.consume();
                }
            });
            return row;
        });
    }
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve - the drop will remove the row from the source table and add the row into the target table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZYL1.gif

When I drag the row from the source to the target, it won't allow the drop:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkEJK.gif

Any assistance would be highly appreciated. 
P.S I do not have 10 rep to make the images viewable inline.

Comment: You're adding the handlers to the rows themselves; if there's no rows then those particular handlers can't be invoked. Consider also adding some handlers to the table itself. When the events are consumed by the handlers on a row they won't propagate up to the table, but when there's no rows then the events will propagate and be handled by the table.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you for the response. I see where you are coming from and I have implemented a fix. I had also found this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153967/how-to-drag-and-drop-entire-rows-between-different-tables-in-javafx) where it outlines what I am wanted to achieve. I had implemented custom methods setOnDragEntered and setOnDragExited to the table itself and I was able to get around my problem. Thanks again for the clarification.