# How can I reorder TableCells by drag and drop in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview

I would like to reorder a tableview column by drag and dropping it's cells.

This is what I tried so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28606524/10949869, but this only works for reordering complete rows. (I'd like to only drag the email part)

Comment: You can't reorder columns independent of each other, if that's what you're asking how to do. In a `TableView` the row _is_ the model item. It wouldn't make sense to move part of the item to another row while not moving the rest.

Comment: @Slaw, in theory, I am guessing it can be done. It's a matter of switching model data. One could take a snapshot and drag it. Once the snapshot is released over the target, switch the model items for the given rows.

Comment: @Sedrick True. In practice that could do what the OP wants (assuming manipulating the model item is acceptable), though conceptually I'd consider it a different operation. The desired functionality makes it seem the OP would be better served using a [`SpreadsheetView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html) from ControlsFX, however.

Comment: @Saw, I agree with you on that.